# Unable to add class dynamically on window resize

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the div to which I am trying to add class

```
<div id="sidebar" class="addthis_recommended_horizontal col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12""></div>
```

and this is the script I am using

```
<script>window.onresize=function()
{var width=document.getElementById("#sidebar").clientWidth;
if(width<640) {document.getElementById("#sidebar").setAttribute("class",".sidebar");}
</script>
```

After adding this class, this CSS code changes the width

```
.sidebar.at4-recommended-item{width:45%!important}
```

But the class was not being added, I don't know why?

**EDIT**
I am using media queries. In this case two classes have same name If I change one other will change too so I am adding a class dynamically, and it is a div not whole window width that I need to change.

**WHY ARE PEOPLE SO KEEN ON DOWNVOTING EVERY QUESTION HERE?**

Comment: You just got only one downvote.. :/   (_I didn't downvote you_)

Comment: The point is this question is not that bad so as to receive a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are changing the element's width on window resize, ideally you should be using CSS3's @media queries instead!

In your case, the @media query will be:

```
<style>
    @media (max-width: 640px){
        #sidebar{
            width: 45%;
        }
    }
</style>
```

It is a bad idea to write Javascript just for this purpose.

*Learn more:* [CSS @media queries | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

***EDIT:***

If you are adding the class dynamically, just mention that in the @media query:

```
<style>
    @media (max-width: 640px){
        .sidebar{
            width: 45%;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Keep it simple. :)

Comment: [Note to OP] media queries doesn't support IE8 and below.

Comment: [Note to OP] Respond.js is mandatory if you want to use mediaqueries in IE8. This is the polyfill that enables media queries for the browser. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7777281/586051).

Comment: I am using media quesies but I can't use them In this case.

Comment: @Asain You can set media query for the dynamically added class too. :) Please see the edit in my answer.

Comment: My width of div does not directly depend on width of window. Width of window is 1366px and width of div is less than 640px

Comment: @Mr_Green IE8 does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `#` when you select an element by `document.getElementById`. `#` is used in css/jQuery selectors, not in plain JavaScript. and also you are adding a class name on window resize to below `640`, you should also consider removing that class when resized above `640`.

Please try using following code:

```
<script>
    window.onresize=function() {
       var sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar");
       var width = sidebar.clientWidth;
       if(width<640) {
           sidebar.className ="sidebar";
       }
       else{
           sidebar.className = ""; //assuming this element doesn't have any other classes.
       }
    }
</script>
```

If you want use jQuery then,

```
<script>
   window.onresize=function() {
       var sidebar = $("#sidebar");
       var width = sidebar.width();
       if(width<640) {
           sidebar.addClass("sidebar");
       }
       else{
           sidebar.removeClass("sidebar");
       }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: There is no `class` but a `className` property. One can also use `.classList.add("sidebar")`.

Comment: "*`#` is only used in jQuery selectors, not in plain JavaScript.*" - `#` is used in CSS selectors, rather than 'jQuery selectors,' and is used in plain JavaScript methods such as `document.querySelector()` and  `document.querySelectorAll()` (among a couple of others).